# Breaking down the parameter on a RadioButtonList / C# asp.net

Tags: c#, sql

Currently I am having a radiobuttonlist that display is base on this:

```
cmds = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT  [invtid] +' '+ [descr] +' '+ [transtatuscode] as ProductDesc FROM [Products] p where ib_itemcode1='" + barcode + "' Order by  transtatuscode ASC ,ib_itemcode1 DESC  ;", conn);
```

from a DataTable and bind ProductDesc:

```
rediobtn.DataTextField = "ProductDesc";
rediobtn.DataBind();
```

Now I want to be able to pull the [invtid] of the selected RadioButtonList. How do I do that? There is only 1 selection.

UPDATE!!
This is the radiobuttonlist

```
            <asp:RadioButtonList Font-Size="X-Small" OnSelectedIndexChanged="radioBtn_SelectedIndexChange" AutoPostBack="true"    RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatColumns="2" ID="rediobtn" runat="server">
```

The code behind i am using is

```
  rediobtn.DataSource = existingSheetQuery.GetSheetItemRadiobutton(value);
        string radioIndex = rediobtn.SelectedValue;
```

But i will end up pulling all the content from ProductDesc. 
I had also change the sql command to

```
cmds = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [invtid], [invtid] +' '+ [descr] +' '+ [transtatuscode] as ProductDesc FROM [Products] p where ib_itemcode1='" + barcode + "' Order by  transtatuscode ASC ,ib_itemcode1 DESC  ;", conn);
```

Comment: `rediobtn` is a single radio button or radiobuttonlist?  What is set to `rediobtn.DataValueField` ? Tried using `rediobtn.SelectedValue`?

Comment: You're having `AS` keyword in `ProductDesc`, why not trying something like `SELECT [invtid], [invtid] +' '+ [descr] +' '+ [transtatuscode] AS ProductDesc FROM Products ...`? Also you can retrieve in code-behind using `rediobtn.SelectedValue`.

Comment: `ProductDesc` is separated by blank spaces so if you split the selected value by a space then it would be at index 0. Of course that means `invtid` better not have spaces. A better solution is to write your query so it selects all fields separately, the id of the record and the combined description as you have now. Then when a radio button is selected you look up the selected id to get the `invtid`. You should also edit your question and indicate if this is a web app, windows form etc so you can get better answers.

Comment: @CodingYoshi i get what u meant but i do not know how to join query in a radiobuttonlist.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i tried but i will get the whole chunk of data which i only need invtid.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes i tried that but how do i assign to only the invtid instead of productDesc.

Comment: @phan Is `rediobtn.DataValueField = "invtid"` enough? You can provide text & value fields separately. But I think better to separate columns like `SELECT [invtid], [descr], [transtatuscode] FROM Products ...` and concatenate strings in code-behind instead of SQL query string.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it is possible , however the radiobuttonlist will only display the invtid, i need it to display in this format, invtid - descr - transtatuscode.